# Problems with running "vagrant up"

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

When I execute "vagrant up" I see the following error message:

```
% vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] -- 3000 => 3333 (adapter 1)
[default] -- 5678 => 5678 (adapter 1)
[default] -- 27017 => 27017 (adapter 1)
[default] -- 28017 => 28017 (adapter 1)
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.
```

I tried to start the virtual machine from VirtualBox UI, but I receive the following error:

> where: supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime what:  4
>   VERR_VM_DRIVER_VERSION_MISMATCH (-1912) - The installed support driver
>   doesn't match the version of the user.

This error seems to be quite common, so there a lot of advices in the Internet about how to fix it. Here are some commands that I've tried before:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox
```

But it didn't help.

Here are versions of software that I use:

```
% VBoxManage --version
4.3.34_Ubuntur104062
% lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried reinstalling Vagrant and VirtualBox but it didn't help.

I only was able to run my VM only after I reinstalled Ubuntu and installed VirtualBox and Vagrant in the following way:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install virtualbox-4.3
sudo apt-get -y install virtualbox-dkms

sudo apt-get -y install vagrant
```